# Application of maximum principle in a circle

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Let $C(0,1) \subset \mathbb C$ be the unit circle. The question is to compute
$$ \max_{z \in C(0,1)} \vert z^2+1 \vert.$$
Apparently one can use the maximum principle to do so but I really don't see how. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimate $|z^2+1|\le|z|^2+1\le 1+1=2$ and note that $z=1$ gives equality.

Comment: Yeah I know I can do that way but I'm confused that this exercice is in the section maximum principle but I don't see how it can be used here.

Comment: There's no point doing it any other way. That said, given that it's so elementary, are you sure you are stating the exercise correctly? Is the problem from a textbook? If so, what book, what exercise, what chapter?

Comment: Ok I just checked with the one that wrote the exercice it is a mistake the right question is to find the maximum on $\overline{D(0,1)}$ (and now the application of the maximum principe is straightforward) but thanks anyway.

Comment: There is always a point doing it other ways. To learn new methods of course.

Comment: @Héhéhé The solution for $\overline{D(0,1)}$ is literally identical as $|z|\le 1$. Honestly, I can hardly see any more advanced maximum modulus principle here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$|z^2+1|^2 = (z^2+1)\overline{(z^2+1)}$$
Where $\overline w$ is complex conjugate of $w$ and use that $.^2$ is monotonic increasing. Now you can expand and investigate right hand side with your favourite technique.